# Calculate the radius and intervall of convergence

Tags: analysis, convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion

We have the function $f(x)=x\cdot \ln (x)$.

I have calculated the Taylor series \begin{align*}T(x)&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(1)}{n!}(x-1)^n\\ & =\frac{f^{(0)}(1)}{0!}(x-1)^0+\frac{f^{(1)}(1)}{1!}(x-1)^1+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(1)}{n!}(x-1)^n  \\ & =0+(x-1)+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n(n-2)!}{n!}(x-1)^n \\ & =(x-1)+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n(n-1)}(x-1)^n\end{align*} To calculate the radius and intervall of convergence do we have to write this term as one sum? Or is it possible to calculate that also in that form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first term $x-1$ has no effect on the radius of convergence. By root test the radius is $1$. So the sreis convers for $0 <x<2$ it is also absolutely convergent for $x=0$ and $x=2$ by comparison with $\sum \frac 1 {n^{2}}$.

Comment: So the intervall ofconvergence is $(1-1, 1+1)=(0,2)$and we have to check also the boundary points $0$ and $2$, right?

Comment: Yes and it converges at the end points also. I have edited my answer @MaryStar

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!! :-)

Answer (score 0):

It is well-known that

$$\log(z+1)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n+1}\frac{z^n}{n}$$ has the radius of convergence $1$. Multiplying by the polynomial $z+1$ has no effect on that radius.

---

By the way, this establishes that the general term of the development is, for $n>1$,

$$(-1)^{n+1}\frac{z^n}{n}+(-1)^{n}\frac{z^{n-1}}{n-1}z=(-1)^{n}\frac{z^n}{n(n-1)}.$$

Comment: By the second part you ean that we can write $T(x)$ all as a sum, and not to write the term $x-1$ seperately?

Comment: @MaryStar: er, no.